# What should be used as an url in url_launcher to make the flutter app open in-built camera on device?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, camera

I learned that we can launch google maps and emails and skype from url_launcher. What should be the URL for opening in the built camera app of the phone?

both in Android and iOS?

```
const url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=52.32,4.917';
const url1 = 'cam:'; //what should be this url? 
if (await canLaunch(url1)) {
  await launch(url1);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't open the camera from url_launcher, you need a package called [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) so you can get the picture or video from the built-in camera.